# Express 4 & Passport Unable to Create Session

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I have been able this far to log users in using Facebook. However, once I recover the information from Facebook I lose it.

I do not know if I should be the one who creates the session or I am missing something out.

This is what I have done: Configuration

```
var passport = require('passport');
passport.use(
  new FacebookStrategy(
    {
      clientID: FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
      clientSecret: FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
      callbackURL: 'http://localhost:8080/auth/facebook/callback'
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      process.nextTick(function() {
        //Assuming user exists
        console.log("CALLBACK passport.use", profile);
        return done(null, profile); //SHOWS THE USER
      });
    }
  )
);
```

Serialization and deserialization, both `console.log` show correctly the user

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  console.log("SERIALIZE USER", user)
  done(null, user); //SHOWS USER
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, done) {
  console.log("DESERIALIZE USER", obj)
  done(null, obj); //SHOWS USER
});
```

Inside the cluster (1 of 4), it makes correctly the redirection to `/success`. **However**, the `console.log` of the `success`controller shows undefined. I have tried without clusters, and the issue remains the same...

```
else if (!cluster.isMaster) {
//...
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());

    app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook'));
    app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
       passport.authenticate('facebook', {
           successRedirect : '/success',
           failureRedirect : '/'
       }));

    app.get('/success', function(req, res, next) {
      console.log("\n\n\nSESSION", req.user); //SHOWS req.user as UNDEFINED ;(
      res.send('Successfully logged in.');
    });
```

Comment: The facebook profile result is only once returned, also are you sure the cookie has been setup correctly ? Does the problem occur even without using the cluster module ?

Comment: Try putting     app.use(passport.initialize()); before passport serializeUser and deserializeUser functions.

Comment: Which session store are you using?

Comment: @robertklep I was assuming that `app.use(passport.session())` deal with all that, I do not know what session store I am using

Comment: @JoseMato I tried it, but the issue continued

Comment: @RistoNovik I do not know if the cookie is being setup correctly. I tried without using clusters, but the issue continued

Comment: @eversor that only hooks up Passport to the Express session system. But you need some sort of persistent session store ([`express-session`](https://github.com/expressjs/session) supports various types) if you want to share sessions across different processes. By default, `express-session` uses an in-memory store (per process).

Comment: @eversor can you extract the full runnable code ?

Comment: @robertklep THANK YOU! If you do not mind, please answer the question so I can mark it as accepted ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passport uses the session middleware that Express is configured to use, which usually is [`express-session`](https://github.com/expressjs/session).

By default, this middleware uses an in-memory store to keep the session data in, but aside from this not being persistent across restarts of your app and having known memory leaks, the session data is not shared across your various worker processes (the in-memory storage area is per-process).

Some kind of shared session store that can be used across all worker processes should be used instead. There are [various options](https://github.com/expressjs/session#compatible-session-stores), of which I think the Redis and MongoDB stores are most popular.